# Cannot resolve symbol CompletionAwareAggregationStrategy, TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy

Tags: apache-camel, timeout, aggregate, spring-camel, completion

I'm migrating a Spring 2.6 project from Apache Camel v2.25.4 to v3.14, the last version that is compatible with Java 8. I'm using Maven as package manager.

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'CompletionAwareAggregationStrategy', TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy'
```

Apparently, these interfaces are removed from version 3.0.0 onwards, but I couldn't find any information about it in the migration guide. The only related step is the following:
[Camel Upgrade guide to 3.7 - Modularized core](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_7.html#_modularized_core).

They are still mentioned in the documentation for version 3.14:

- [AGGREGATING ON TIMEOUT](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/aggregate-eip.html#_completionawareaggregationstrategy:%7E:text=TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy)
- [COMPLETIONAWAREAGGREGATIONSTRATEGY](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/aggregate-eip.html#_completionawareaggregationstrategy:%7E:text=aggregation%20strategy%20implements-,CompletionAwareAggregationStrategy,-%2C%20then%20Camel%20will)

I have tried importing other packages like the ones mentioned in the migration guide:

- camel-core-model
- camel-core-reifier
- camel-core-processor

But I had no success finding the symbols.

I have also tried implementing my classes with these related interfaces, but they don't extend 'AggregationStrategy' interface, so it's not what I'm looking for.

- [FlexibleAggregationStrategy.TimeoutAwareMixin](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-core-model/3.14.0/org/apache/camel/builder/FlexibleAggregationStrategy.TimeoutAwareMixin.html)
- [FlexibleAggregationStrategy.CompletionAwareMixin](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-core-model/3.14.0/org/apache/camel/builder/FlexibleAggregationStrategy.CompletionAwareMixin.html)

If they have been removed from Apache Camel, then how do you suggest I replace the interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are out of the box on `org.apache.camel.AggregationStrategy` as default methods.